# MTOM/SSL: Hang is occurring when accessing web service using MTOM and SSL via Java

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, jaxb, mtom

I have created a web service client in Java that was successfully calling a web service using JAXB and a client proxy and using MTOM to send binary data.

The service now requires SSL.  After updating my client code to provide an SSL connection, I can make calls successfully that don't require a binary attachment, but the one that does require binary attachment hangs.  A response is never received from the service.  Eventually my client times out.

How can I get this to work?  Do I need to do something special to enable MTOM when using SSL?  I've searched this site and the web and see no other reports of this.

I have a little information from someone that watched network packets on the server side.  I paraphrase, because I don't fully understand: He says that TLS is started and data transfers, but then it goes into a TLS encryption handshake again and stalls.  He wonders if there is a separate TLS session that is generated for the MTOM and my application thinks there is already a TLS session established and doesn't go through the initial exchange of certificates like it should.  I don't know how to check that out, since it's all down in low-level library code and I don't have source for it.

I'm very, very new to web services and SSL.

The code to create the web service is as follows:

```
private MyService getService() throws Exception {

    SSLHelper.initializeConduitForSSL(new File("d:/keystore.jks"), "jks", "changeit");

    final JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();

    factory.setServiceClass(MyService.class);
    factory.setAddress("https://" + endPoint);  // endpoint not shown in this code
    service = (MyService)factory.create();

    final Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(service);
    final HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit)client.getConduit();

    http.setTlsClientParameters(SSLHelper.getTlsParams());
    final Map<String, Object> ctxt = ((BindingProvider)publishingService).getRequestContext();

    // Enable HTTP chunking mode, otherwise HttpURLConnection buffers
    ctxt.put(JAXWSProperties.HTTP_CLIENT_STREAMING_CHUNK_SIZE, 8192);

    return service;
}
```

To make a request, I call methods on the returned service object.

SSLHelper is my own class that handles the certificate setup.  I believe that part is not the issue, so I won't include that setup code here.  (Since I can make other requests with the same SSL configuration, I'm assuming this isn't the issue.)

For the MTOM call, the method takes an argument that is an instance of a request class that has a field (with appropriate setter) specified as such:

```
@XmlElement(required = true)
@XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")
private DataHandler dataHandler;
```

To initialize this class, I do the following:

```
File file = new File("c:\\somefile.jpg"); // 
final DataSource dataSource = new FileDataSource(file);
request.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
```

DataHandler and FileDataSource are in javax.activation package.

One last thing.  The owners of the service are able to successfully call this request using MTOM, but they are using the following to enable SSL:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
```

I can't do that, because within the same JVM, we are using more than one key store to connect with different web services.